# PTB treebank from CoNLL-X

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a CoNLL-X format treebank and the corresponding binary parse tree for each sentence and I want to convert it into a PTB format. Is there any converters or can anyone shed light on the PTB format?

Answer (score 3):

There's been a number of efforts to convert from dependencies (representable in [CoNLL-X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416164/what-is-conll-data-format) format) to constituents (representable in [Penn Treebank](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/), or PTB, format). Two recent papers and their code:

1. [Transforming Dependencies into Phrase Structures](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~nasmith/papers/kong+rush+smith.naacl15.pdf) (Kong, Rush, and Smith, NAACL 2015). [Code](https://github.com/ikekonglp/PAD).
2. [Parsing as Reduction](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~afm/Home_files/acl2015_reduction.pdf) (Fernandez-Gonzalez and Martins, ACL 2015). [Code](https://github.com/andre-martins/TurboParser/tree/labeler).