# How to get constituency-based parse tree from Parsey McParseface

Tags: nlp, syntaxnet, parsey-mcparseface

Parsey McParsey returns a dependency-based parse tree by default, but is their a way to get a constituency-based parse tree from it?

EDIT: To clarify, by "to get from it" I mean from the Parsey itself. Though building a tree from ConLL output would be an option too.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442907/ptb-treebank-from-conll-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have investigated this, and I believe that the answer is that you cannot get a constituency parse directly from Parsey McParseface or any other syntaxnet model.

Constituency parses are [fundamentally different from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401076/difference-between-constituency-parser-and-dependency-parser) dependency parses, and syntaxnet is designed to produce dependency parses. Indeed, the [CoNLL format](http://universaldependencies.org/docs/format.html) that syntaxnet gives output in is not even capable of representing a constituency parse tree:

> The HEAD and DEPREL fields are used to encode a **dependency** tree over words