# How to convert from column-based CoNLL format to the Penn Treebank annotation style?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, penn-treebank

Does anybody know about any tool, script, etc. to convert from column-based CoNLL format to the Penn Treebank annotation style?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442907/ptb-treebank-from-conll-x/37376956#37376956

Answer (score 1):

As has been related in other threads on this topic, it's actually an open area of research to convert dependency parses into constituency parses.  Stanford CoreNLP has no functionality for attempting this at this time.