# spacy convert conllul to spacy json format

Tags: nlp, spacy

I get data from Universal Dependencies I work mostly with Indonesian (bahasa) so I clone the repo:

- https://github.com/conllul/UL_Indonesian-PUD
- https://github.com/conllul/UL_Indonesian-GSD

both repo contains bz2 file and after unpack I get the contained files. everything there is in conllul format. so I tried to convert it to spacy's json format using command :

`python -m spacy convert thefile.conllul .`

however, spacy throwing error message :

`Unknown format
    Can't find converter for conllul`

how to do the conversion? 
is `conllul` and `conll` format is the same thing? if not, how do I convert `conllul` to `conll` format? thx in advance

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let's clarify things a bit, before answering your question.

The following statements are true:

- There are different ConNLL formats
- The different formats have in common that they derive from [CoNLL](http://www.conll.org/2018) conference.
- Spacy provides a converter via its CLI for 2 different formats: the simple conll format and the most recent conllu format. You can find more about the conll format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416164/what-is-conll-data-format) and more about conllu format [here](http://universaldependencies.org/format.html)
- Conllul is a different data format, presented in 2018. You can read more [here](https://conllul.github.io/)
- Spacy does not support directly conversion between conllul and json format.

Having all that in mind, the answer to your question I guess it would be to use a conllu format for your language, which is a standard way to work with natural language data with spacy. I have found that there is data in the format in the ud treebank collection for your language. You can download the data from [here](https://github.com/UniversalDependencies/UD_Indonesian-GSD) and then use spacy converter to convert them to json.

I really hope it helped. :)