# How to save a dependency graph as image in NLTK Python

Tags: python, nltk, dependency-graph

I found a few posts including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661360/save-a-dependecy-graph-in-python) on how to generate a dependency graph. However, I'm looking for an option to export a dependency graph as a PNG/SVG image.

For simplicity, let's assume we already parsed a sentence `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.` and we have the output in [to_conll(4)](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/_modules/nltk/parse/dependencygraph.html#DependencyGraph.to_conll) format. Now if pass this result to the `DependencyGrpah` class

```
from nltk.parse import DependencyGraph
DependencyGraph(
'''The  DT  4   det
quick   JJ  4   amod
brown   JJ  4   amod
fox NN  5   nsubj
jumps   VBZ 0   ROOT
over    IN  9   case
the DT  9   det
lazy    JJ  9   amod
dog NN  5   obl
.   .   5   punct'''
)
```

It produces the following the image

[image: dependency graph in nltk]

**My question is how can I save this image as a PNG/SVG file?**

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it from a `.ps` to a `.png`.

```
import os
from nltk.draw.tree import TreeView

TreeView(GRAPH)._cframe.print_to_file('tree.ps')
os.system('convert tree.ps tree.png')
```

Comment: What Python version did you use? Mine is `3.8` and it's showing `tclerror: no display name and no $display environment variable` error. And unfortunately, I can't go to a lower version.

Comment: @AbuShoeb are you using an OS X device?

Comment: No, it's a Linux machine but the Jupyter notebook is running as a container.

Comment: I see it works for me, this answer does not work on Linux then, I will try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VScode to experiment with notebook files, there is a small icon at the right upper corner. then there will be an icon in the right upper corner to save your graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`to_dot()`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html#nltk.parse.dependencygraph.DependencyGraph.to_dot) on your DataGraph object, and then proceed to [create a Graphviz object from raw](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#using-raw-dot) and then save it into a file with `render`.

You can choose both the filename and the format (png, pdf...), as reported in the [method signature](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Source.render)

Comment: Would it be able to save it as PNG instead of PDF?